# Does a cylinder with equal height and diameter have a special name?

Tags: geometry, terminology, solid-geometry

I'm working on z-calibration part for my 3d-printer and I'm wondering if this has a special name?

```
cylinder({r: 5, h: 10})
```

Basically a cylinder that has a height which is equal to its width.  In this case, the rendered model would be 10mm high by 10mm in diameter. Also, are there any other interesting properties of this form?

Comment: As far as I know, $2\times10\ne10$.

Comment: Where do you see 2 * 10 = 10?

Comment: also, down votes should be accompanied by comments, no?

Comment: Didn't you write height 2x diameter ? When you get such comments, it is time to question yourself.

Comment: Ah, my bad, didn't even see the title.  =) . Updated, thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no special name as such a cylinder is not "special" enough (no particular application, no remarkable property). You might risk cube-inscribed cylinder or cubocylindre (?).

Comment: That cylinder has the [minimal surface area among all cylinders with the same volume](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141849/why-does-the-cylinder-with-minimum-surface-area-have-a-height-equal-to-its-diame), which is kind of an interesting property.

Comment: @Wouter: good point. That makes it a "minimal isoperimetric cylinder".

Comment: Cool.  I suppose one of the few applications is calibrating a cartesian 3d printer, since it allows you to check 3 axes in one result. Thanks.

Comment: @4m1r: I understand that it is convenient to have $h=d$ so that the object has a single dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out by @Wouter in the comments above, it is the "ideal tin can", having minimal surface area for a given volume. but the converse is also true: it has maximum volume for a given surface area

Comment: I found this smart article about the "Tin-Can mystery" http://www.niquette.com/puzzles/tin-canp.htm

Comment: @YvesDaoust: interesting article. Thanks for that.

Comment: Interesting article.  Amazing how much thought (or intuition) went into the the humble tin can.  In the case of h = d, maybe it should be called a "sqylinder"? =)

Comment: I suggest "cubelinder".