# How to solve this optimization problem? (w/o values in the question)

Tags: calculus, optimization

I've encountered this problem while studying for a test but I can't quite get how to do it. The question is:

A closed cylinder tank is to be made with a fixed volume. Find the relative dimensions of the tank which will require the least amount of material in making it.

There are no values given in the question. How should I approach this?

Comment: You need to find the cylinder's radius-to-height ratio that minimizes its total surface. The majority of the problem is already solved [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127569/optimization-with-cylinder).

Comment: @Naja so it's looking for the surface area of the cylinder, right?